# Is jumping out of global main still considered as part of main function, in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Is part of the code, which we access with calling jmp, still considered part of main function in assembly?

Example:

```
main:
    mov ebx,3 
    push ebx 
    jmp for_loop ; this part
rec:
    ;some function
for_loop:
    ;logic
    je exit 
    call rec
    ;logic
    jmp for_loop
exit:
    pop ebx 
    mov eax,0 
    ret
```

Would it be a better practice to not use jmp and write `for_loop` under `main`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that looks a bit like a mess.

There is no main function in assembly. You might call the entry point, where execution begins, "main", but that's really it. It's just imaginary labels not existing in the machine code. A function would be anything you `call`, because the processor's `call` instruction does some setting-up when he `jmp`s to it, but that's it already.

Personally, I'd restructure this quite a bit.

```
main:
    xor ebx,ebx
    add ebx,3           ; saves a byte
    push ebx
forloop:
    ; I assume here you do a dec, or cmp, for the following:
    je exit
    ; put the code for "rec" in here.
    ; No point wasting the bytes and time to jump.
    jmp forloop
exit:
    pop ebx
    xor eax,eax
    ret
```

Okay, so this still is kind of a mess, but there's holes in my knowledge about what you're trying to achieve.

The `je exit` at the beginning probably connects to the "logic" that is supposed to go before that. I'd personally rather try to unscramble this, turning it around. That means, assuming the "logic" allows me to do so, I would turn it into a `jne forloop` and put it at the end of the loop, so i can avoid that jmp to the beginning. Also saves you a few bytes again.

The `xor eax,eax` is a shorter, quicker way of setting a register to zero. If you really *need* `rec` to be a seperate function, then at least put it outside of this block so you don't have to jump over it using `jmp for_loop`. You could safely put it after the `ret`.

Comment: Editted the `jne exit`to `jne forloop`, because else it wouldn't work.

Comment: How do you figure that `xor`+`add` "saves a byte"? That is 2+3 bytes, whereas `mov ebx, 3` is *also* 5 bytes. Same. Prefer the single instruction.

Comment: errr, you're right of course. I was stuck at the `xor` being shorter, ignoring that the `add` equalises it.

Answer (score 1):

The whole part:

```
rec:
    ; some function (ending with ret?!)
```

can be moved after the `ret` which is in the `exit:` part of code, then you will have "main" together, and "rec" separately, like this:

```
main:
   ; some init
   ; some loop doing "call rec"
   ; something something
   ret

rec:
   ; some "function" code
   ret
```

Then again, it doesn't matter **to CPU** at all, it's not aware in any way what is your logical grouping of instructions in the source or whether it is inside some "function" and "how deep".

The CPU has `cs:eip` address pointer from where it will fetch+execute next instruction. That's all it does know at particular moment of execution.

The `jmp` instruction loads `eip` with other address, then instruction there is next to be executed.

The "subroutines" mechanism works through storing return addresses into stack memory, which are then loaded back into `eip` by `ret` instruction, but if you adjust the stack content by other means to contain invalid return address, or different one, the `ret` will crash or "jump" to other address, the CPU has no idea it was "inside" some subroutine, nor does it have any need to "return" out of it. All of that is high-level semantic logic written by programmer, who is responsible to design the execution-paths correctly, to form such logical patterns like "calls of subroutines" or "main loops".

CPU has only `cs:eip` and content of other registers and content of memory, nothing else. Whatever that state is ahead of instruction execution, it deterministically imposes what instruction will be executed next and what effect it will have - to the content of CPU registers and computer memory (and other connected chips, either by I/O bus or by using certain parts of memory as "mapped" I/O control mechanism).

---

So to put it in other way around, write your source for easy "reading" by human, don't hesitate to invest more time into writing easier/leaner source, as you will *READ* the source many times more (debugging, modifying), than *WRITING* it. So in your example it makes lot more sense to move "rec" part of code out, to not interleave the main-loop-ret chain of "main code". It should read better on source level.

> Is part of the code, which we access with calling jmp, still considered part of main function in assembly?

Depends on the reader of source, whether she considers it part of main or not. The machine doesn't care or understand such concept of instruction grouping.